# SQL - Excluding Null Values after Joining Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to programming and learning SQL. I'm trying to exclude NULL values after ORDER BY ... DESC. Can you please help with working this out. Also not sure if I should be using WHERE or HAVING,

```
-- Which director has the highest total domestic takings
SELECT d.first_name, d.last_name, SUM(mr.domestic_takings) AS total_dom_takings
FROM directors d
-- *** WHERE/HAVING mr.domestic_takings IS NOT NULL ***
JOIN movies mo ON d.director_id = mo.director_id
JOIN movie_revenues mr ON mo.movie_id = mr.movie_id
GROUP BY d.first_name, d.last_name
ORDER BY total_dom_takings DESC;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the `WHERE` clause completely.

Most aggregate functions, among them `sum`, ignore NULL arguments anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the WHERE clause after  JOIN:

```
SELECT d.first_name, d.last_name, SUM(mr.domestic_takings) AS total_dom_takings
FROM directors d
JOIN movies mo ON d.director_id = mo.director_id
JOIN movie_revenues mr ON mo.movie_id = mr.movie_id
WHERE mr.domestic_takings IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d.first_name, d.last_name
ORDER BY total_dom_takings DESC;
```